# Can't get a div to horizontal align in ie 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

Works fine in all browsers other then ie6 and ie7 but I am concerned only with ie7 for this issue.

I am trying to have a nav bar stick to the bottom of the browser window and stay in position when the page is scrolled

Nav Bar Code

```
<div id="quickcontactbar" style="align: center;">
    <p class="leftp">
        <a><img src="/images/searchbutton.png" style="border-right: 1px solid #888;"></a>
        <iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/follow_button.html?screen_name=micrimdefense&link_color=ffffff" style="width:165px; height:20px;"></iframe>
        <g:plusone size="medium" count="false"></g:plusone>
        <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=140269382715400&amp;href&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=60&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border-right: 1px solid #888; overflow:hidden; width:60px; height:21px;padding-left: 3px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
        <span style="padding-left: 75px;"><img src="/images/phonenumber.png" style="border-right: 1px solid #888;border-left: 1px solid #888;"></span>
        <img src="/images/copyright.png">
    </p>
</div>
```

This is the css for the navbar

```
#quickcontactbar {
   position: fixed;
   width: 808px;
   height: 36px;
   bottom:0px;
   left:0px;
   right:0px;
   background: url(images/bgquickbar.png);
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
   margin: 0 auto;
   display:block;
   text-align: center;
   }

#quickcontactbar .leftp {
   color: #e3fe54;
   margin: 5px;
   font-weight: bolder;
   font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 16px;
   padding-top: 7px;
   padding-left: 5px;
   height:16px;
   }
```

I suspect it has something to do with the `left:0px` and `right:0px`, but when I remove those it breaks in all other browsers and moves the nav bar off the screen to the right.

Thanks for the help, Stack Overflow rocks

also, I force standards mode with

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

In ie7 showing the problem...

[image: img193.imageshack.us/img193/2569/screenshot20110802at427.png]

It should display like in chrome/ie8/safari...

[image: img402.imageshack.us/img402/231/screenshot20110802at428.png]

Comment: You're forcing your code into "standards mode" but you're not following standards in your code.  Run it through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: Why are you setting the width to 808 pixels?  How can it be 0 pixels from left/right edges while also constrained to a specific width?  This is a conflict.  Telling it to be 0 pixels from left/right edges is the same as telling it to match its width to the window.

Comment: I used a wrapper to center it while also keeping it 808 pixels wide... see my updated answer.  Should work on IE... let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `style="align: center;"` from this...

```
<div id="quickcontactbar" style="align: center;">
```

making it into this...

```
<div id="quickcontactbar">
```

AFAIK, there is no such thing as `align:` in CSS and you already have `text-align: center;` applied to the `<div>` in your CSS.

Also validate your code with the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

**EDIT:**

Looking at part of your CSS here...

```
#quickcontactbar {
   width: 808px;
   left:0px;
   right:0px;
   }
```

The width is in constant conflict with the left/right positioning.  How can it be both `0px` from the left **and** right while also being `808px` wide?  When your browser window is 1000 pixels wide, the left/right is positioning the div 0 pixels from the left edge and 0 pixels from the right edge which forces the `<div>` to be 1000 pixels wide.  That is how that is supposed to work.  Now how can the browser reconcile that with your declaration that it must only be 808 pixels wide?

**EDIT 2:**

Use an 808 pixel wide wrapper `<div>` to horizontally center everything within.

http://jsfiddle.net/8rvQ3/4/

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="quickcontactbar">
         <p class="leftp">
               .....
         </p>
    </div>
</div>


#wrapper {
   position: relative;
   width: 808px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
#quickcontactbar {
   position: fixed;
   width: 808px;
   height: 36px;
   bottom: 0;
   background: url(images/bgquickbar.png);
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
   display:block;
   text-align: center;
}
#quickcontactbar .leftp {
   color: #e3fe54;
   margin: 5px;
   font-weight: bolder;
   font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 16px;
   padding-top: 7px;
   padding-left: 5px;
   height: 16px;
}
```

Comment: that was left in from trying to fix it - removed it does not do anything. Code does not validate, as the iframe instances and google plus button will not validate.

Comment: @dunivanb: Validate what you can and leave the third party code alone.  Also, can you exactly explain what is going wrong in IE?

Comment: sure: ie7 (http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/2569/screenshot20110802at427.png) should display like chrome/ie8/safari (http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/231/screenshot20110802at428.png)

Comment: IE7 is ignoring `right:0px;` and the other browsers are ignoring `left:0px; right:0px;`.  While at the same time all browsers are respecting `width: 808px;`.  See my updated answer.

Comment: I do get your point with that, but removing any three of the aspects: width, left, or right breaks the intended function of the nav bar. is there a way to make ie7 work the way all others do?

Comment: right and fixed is the only way to make it scroll with the page, thanks for the help sparky672

Comment: @dunivanb:  Using a wrapper to center a fixed div.  See update.

Answer (score -1):

What happens when you remove left:0 and right:0?

Another way would be to set left: 50%, remove right: 0 and set margin-left: -404px;

Comment: When I remove left and right: it breaks in all other browsers and moves the nav bar off the screen to the right
when i do the margin fix, it pushes everything off the screen aligned right.